# is it possible for background image to not blocking the url links that under it?

Tags: html, css

i've list of links with text, and i want to add background image on it using position: absolute
but the problem is, if the background image is not using z-index higher than links, then the image will not fully show, so i have to add z-index on it. But the problem if i add it, then i can't click on the links because it's blocked by background image. Any idea how to solve this?

[image: This is background image using z-index]

[image: without z-index]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CSS attribute to your image as `pointer-events: none;`.